# 75kva three phase 208v delta to three phase 208v y transformer wiring/results?

Tags: transformer, three-phase

I recently purchased a used 75kva 208v delta to 208v Y transformer and have some concerns about some strange results.  We would like to use this transformer to create separate (isolated) service between audio and lighting systems.

I wired up the ground and then wired the H1, H2 and H3 terminals to the three hots coming out of my buildings 3 phase 208v service. I disregarded the neutral as its not used in delta.  I didn't think the phase order would matter, but I tripped the breakers when I turned it on.  After swapping phases the transformer came to life with a lovely buzz like they always do.

I took out my meter and got some strange results.  I was happy with my 3 hot to hot results (between 208v-210v) and hot to neutral results (between 121v-122v), but For some reason I have 7 volts between ground and neutral.  I also got strange results between hots and ground.  X1 reads 110volts while X2 and X3 both read between 120-122volts.  I could bond the ground and neutral, but it kind of defeats the purpose of why I bought the transformer.

Lastly, I metered the current draw with no load. Black phase (H3)reads 14.32amps, red phase (H1) reads 11.08amps and blue (H2) reads 9.47amps.  I would think they would all be the same.

In summary, I've never hooked up a transformer before so I don't know if the results I got are to be expected.  Seems like something is wrong on the H1/X1 phase.  Kinda feel like I was sold a lemon.  Thoughts?

[image: Input Wiring]
[image: Wiring diagram]

Comment: Consulting a licensed electrician is probably the best plan.

Comment: Where'd you get a 208V delta from? 208V service is just about always wye -- which means you have the transformer wired wrong, so no wonder your results are fubar :P

Comment: As someone with 20 years of experiance providing generators and temporary electrical systems for special events, I am not a noob to electrical wiring.  I'd just like to know if my results are typical or not.  I also think it's important for anyone else installing a transformer to know what typical results are.  Many "licensed" electricians have never installed a transformer like this before.

Comment: The transformer is 208 delta to 208 Y.  My buildings service is 208 Y. Am I correct that you just disregard the neutral when hooking up in delta fashion?  We've rented a similar transformer before and that's how it is connected.

Comment: @Dan To clarify what ThreePhaseEel seems to be asking, you connected the delta side of the transformer to your building's Y service, rather than the Y side to the Y service? I don't know much about three-phase power, so maybe that's a reasonable thing to do, but it's at least counter-intuitive.

Comment: The reason for the transformer to to isolate the neutrals between the two services.  When the lights dim we can't have a buzz in the sound system.  We need an independent neutral which is where the 208 delta to 208 y comes in.

Comment: Rereading that and I seem to be rambling on about what I need it for and overlooking the clarity of my answer.  Let me try that again.  Yes, the delta (primary) side is wired to my building's wye service.  It is my understanding that delta devices can be wired to wye by simply disregarding the neutral.  the wye (secondary) side is where I have the voltages issues between ground/neutral and between one phase and ground.  Hope that clarifies everything.

Comment: I would edit the question to incorporate all these changes. Also a sketch would be nice...

Comment: 7 volts between ground and neutral - why are you surprised - there is no connection other than capacitive between primary and secondary so something round about 0V +/- X volts is to be expected. maybe you have left out some information somewhere?

Comment: One odd thing is that you tripped the breaker at first. The order of the phases really does not matter. There might have been something mis-wired the first time?

Comment: The voltage between ground and neutral is fine. They are actually floating with respect to each other, so measuring 7 volts is not surprising. Measuring the hot legs against ground should reflect the same 7 volts (they are also floating), so those voltages are reasonable.

Comment: But the current is odd, assuming you had nothing hooked up to the secondaries. Could it be a measurement problem?

Comment: @Mark and Andy aka,  thanks for answering the question around the ground/neutral.  I figured it would have some voltage (around 1-2volts) but 7 seemed out of the norm.

Comment: @Mark,  The measurements are correct.  See images. [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FD5Q6.jpg)

[link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nn21R.jpg)

[link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xLqoY.jpg)

Comment: @Mark, the primary wiring is correct (wired to H1/H2/H3) so the breaker tripping is still a questionable issue.  I was almost 100% certain the phase order wouldn’t matter.  I tried every possible combination of black/red/blue to H1/H2/H3.  There are two combinations that do not trip the breakers (Black-H3/Red-H2/Blue-H1 or Black-H1/Blue-H2/Red-H3).  When black is wired to H2 or H3 the breakers trip instantly.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The phase order should not matter and should not trip the phases. You've connected the transformer correctly and discarding the neutral on the primary side is fine. Just to be sure, your MEN is not an open or high leg delta?

The difference in the amp draw can be caused by two things:
- failure in one of the windings 
- unbalance on the primary side

I would suggest to take the following actions:
- run an insulation test on the transformer 
- verify if the unbalance is still within the limits

Also the 7 volts on the neutral will be caused by the phase unbalance.

Comment: This is great.  Thanks for the info.  
Building’s service does not have a high leg.  The voltage was tested and was between 208-210volts across all three phases.   Something else must be wrong with my building’s service because I just hooked the transformer up to one of our 60kw generators and it powers up with any phase order.  It’s just plain weird.

Comment: I also ran the same battery of tests once the transformer was powered by the generator.  The idle current draw was similar to the original results, H3-16amps, H2-10amps and H1-12amps.  The neutral/ground was 7volts, X3 to ground was 111volts, X2 to ground was 118volts and X1 to ground was 122volts.  All three secondary phases were 122volts to neutral.

Comment: Unbalance will probably the cause then. So the phase angles are not 120 degrees. Or one of the windings in the transformer is off. Can you measure the resistance of each winding?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a meter sensitive enough to test the resistance.  Any workaround?

Comment: Can you measure the voltage between the jumpers and ground?